# UIViewController pushViewController, show navigationBar

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have UIViewController(1) without navigationBar, and I need to push anouther UIViewController(2) that have navigationBar, and when I click Back on it, navigationBar must hide on 1 controller. I have tried uiviewcontroller delegates.
But nothing is working..

Please help..

Comment: Are you using storyboards?  Have you set up the first `viewController` inside a `navigationController`?

Comment: yes, I did it, but no result..

Comment: Clarify your question. I understand what you are trying to do. Why isn't it working? Can I see what you have tried? What is happening instead of what you want. The key is in viewWillAppear...

Comment: When you say nothing is working...the 'navigationBar' is showing up when you don't want it to?  The second 'viewcontroller' won't push?  Like Marol1ni said, you need to specify what exactly isn't working.

Comment: Are you using a navigationController anywhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will show the navbar on the second screen:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];        
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```

You will also need to hide the navbar when you return to the first screen:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];        
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Instead of -viewDidDisappear use -viewWillDisappear or else the navigationbar won't be hidden on first screen.

Comment: Use 
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];        
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}

 because  -viewDidDisappear and -viewWillDisappear don't work when you go back to screen 1

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the animated option. If you roll with the approaches above (`self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = value`) you get some undesirable visual crumbs.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

This will push/pop smoothly with the navBar firmly attached to the appearing/disappearing view.

Answer (score 1):

Place this code in first view controller

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];        
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers from Alfie or Ader would be a disaster if you have many viewcontrollers' navigation bar hidden/show state to manage.

I just have posted code dedicated on UINavigationBar appearance management on github. check out [RRViewControllerExtension](https://github.com/Roen-Ro/RRViewControllerExtension), it will solve your problem gracefully.

With [RRViewControllerExtension](https://github.com/Roen-Ro/RRViewControllerExtension), you even don't have to #import the header file, all you have to do is just override any desired method below in your viewcontroller.

```
//override any of the methods below in your viewcontroller's .m file to make specific navigation bar appearance

-(BOOL)prefersNavigationBarHidden;
-(BOOL)prefersNavigationBarTransparent;

-(nullable UIColor *)preferredNavatationBarColor;
-(nullable UIColor *)preferredNavigationItemColor;
-(nullable UIImage *)preferredNavigationBarBackgroundImage;
-(nullable NSDictionary *)preferredNavigationTitleTextAttributes;
```